# move marker realtime from database firebase to mapbox

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tracking, mapbox-gl-js

I want to move a marker based on realtime database firebase like tracking the user. When the database updates the location, mapbox will update the position marker. I have a problem on my website, when javascript get location from database, marker will update but marker becomes duplicates and not delete previous data. So please help me to make delete previous data and just display update marker.
[The code is given below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpwCz.png)
[The result of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPo1P.png)

Comment: Please don't share code as image but instead add into the answer. You can read why here - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new marker each time. Instead you could store each TeamLeader name and the corresponding marker in a json object and just update their coordinates.
you need to create a json object (called `teamLeaderMarkers` in the example), and also store the team leader name (`teamLeaderName` in the example.

Then inside your callback function in setInterval, you'd have something like this:

```
if (teamLeaderMarkers.hasOwnProperty(teamLeaderName)){
    teamLeaderMarkers[teamLeaderName].setLngLat([long,lat]);
} else{
    let marker = new mapboxgl.Marker(el);
     marker.setLngLat([long,lat])
     marker.addTo(map);
    teamLeaderMarkers[teamLeaderName] = marker;
}
```